# jaxb2-annotate-plugin adding broken optional content for lombok annotation

Tags: java, lombok, xjc, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I am using the jaxb2-annotate-plugin to add project lombok annotations to my generated java code.  In some cases, the plugin is adding optional (in this case experimental) extra information to the annotation.

The annotation class is lombok.NoArgsConstructor, which has optional experimental parameter onConstructor

Typical and expected output should simply be:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Foo ...
```

But what I am getting is

```
@NoArgsConstructor(onConstructor = {

})
public class Foo ...
```

I do not want the added parameter (not sure what the proper term for that is), and in addition, it is incorrect, as it requires additional information, in this case, annotations to add to the generated constructor.

So 2 questions:

1. How can I suppress this added information?
2. If I did want this added parameter, how would I add the necessary additional information?

thanks,
Linus

ps.
As an aside not directly related to the question: This plugin is new to me.  I have modified the build.xml file from one of the provided samples to run xjc with the plugin via ant.  While the code is being properly generated, the output appears to say otherwise.  The verbose ant output follows.  The build.xml file is from 
jaxb2-annotate-plugin-master/samples/annotate/target/test-ant-assembly/jaxb2-annotate-plugin-sample-annotate-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT/

> ant -verbose generate-sources     JAVA_HOME:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
>   Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017     Trying
>   the default build file: build.xml      Buildfile:
>   /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/build.xml     Detected
>   Java version: 1.8 in:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>   Detected OS: Mac OS X     parsing buildfile
>   /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/build.xml with URI =
>   file:/Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/build.xml   Project
>   base dir set to: /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2
>   parsing buildfile
>   jar:file:/opt/local/apache-ant-1.10.1/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml
>   with URI =
>   jar:file:/opt/local/apache-ant-1.10.1/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml
>   from a zip file     [property] Loading Environment env.      Override
>   ignored for property "java.home"     Build sequence for target(s)
>   `generate-sources' is [generate-sources]     Complete build sequence
>   is [generate-sources, check, compile, package, install, test-compile,
>   test, clean, ]
>         generate-sources:
>         [xjc] build id of XJC is 2.3.0
>         [xjc] Checking timestamp of /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/bindings.xjb
>         [xjc] Checking timestamp of /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/commonTypes.xjb
>         [xjc] Checking timestamp of /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/person.xjb
>         [xjc] Checking timestamp of /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/variables.xjb
>         [xjc] Checking timestamp of /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/commonTypes.xsd
>         [xjc] Checking timestamp of /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/oads_metadata_a0.2.xsd
>         [xjc] Checking timestamp of /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/person.xsd
>         [xjc] Checking timestamp of /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/variables.xsd
>         [xjc] the last modified time of the inputs is  1553044581000
>         [xjc] the last modified time of the outputs is -9223372036854775808
>         [xjc] Consider using / so that XJC won't do unnecessary compilation
>         [xjc] Compiling file:/Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/commonTypes.xsd and
>   others
>         [xjc] Writing output to /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/gen_src

```
  [xjc] Command invoked: xjc/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
  [xjc] failure in the XJC task. Use the Ant -verbose switch for more details     
  /Users/kamb/workspace/oads_xml/versions/a0.2/build.xml:106: xjc failed
```

> ```
> at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCBase.execute(XJCBase.java:731)   
> at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task.execute(XJC2Task.java:55)  
> at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task.execute(XJC2Task.java:35)    
> at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)  
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
> at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)  
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)  
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)     
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)  
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)     
> at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)    
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)     
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)     
> at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)   
> at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, on further experimentation, I figured it out.

I needed to use the the Java style annotations, not what I guess is the Old Style which I picked up from looking at older SE questions.  So, instead of:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='typed_string_type']">
  <annox:annotate>
    <annox:annotate annox:class="lombok.Builder" />
    <annox:annotate annox:class="lombok.NoArgsConstructor" />
    <annox:annotate annox:class="lombok.AllArgsConstructor" />
  </annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I needed to use:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='value_with_unit_type']">
    <annox:annotate>@lombok.Builder</annox:annotate>
    <annox:annotate>@lombok.NoArgsConstructor</annox:annotate>
    <annox:annotate>@lombok.AllArgsConstructor</annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

So simple.